# iOS detect *physical* rotation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, rotation

I'm writing an app, and on a certain controller I want to force the app into landscape, which I am able to do with this code:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
         let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
         UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")

         addRotationGraphic()
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyClass.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}


@objc func rotated() {
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
        rotationView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

So the view is already forced into landscape upon loading the controller, but I want to detect when the user actually rotates the device to match the orientation I've forced.  Is this possible?  The following code does not seem to fire when you rotate to the orientation I've already laid out for, it is called for rotating further, but I want it to fire when the user rotates the device to match the orientation.  Is this possible?

Comment: You could use Core Motion to detect the device's orientation in space, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: "I want to detect when the user actually rotates the device to match the orientation I've forced."  Why don't you just lock the orientation to landscape?

Comment: There are a few view lifecycle overrides that trigger when **physical** orientation changes. I'd suggest starting with `override func viewWillTransition(to size:, with coordinator:)` to start. And to be safe, don't use size classes (BIG mistake for iPads) or `UIDevice.current.orientation`. Simply check the bounds.

Comment: @ElTomato I only want this to happen for a specific controller in my app, so I don't want to lock it the rest of the app.  I'm basically giving a helpful indicator to rotate the device when getting to a certain point in the app.

Comment: I actually am in similar situation right now but looks like dead end. I can detect orientation change but not actual orientation because I forced it the same way as you.